# Firebase Get Dynamic Field Value in Recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have below firebase structure where user_id has passed as a key, now I need to retreive this value in recyclerview but finding no way how to get this value inside my recyclerview

[image]

I have tried a value event listener inside my bind method to get the value but not working below is the code i tried

```
final DatabaseReference bookref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("nfjir_cPtfjdueru9piy").child("b");

bookref.orderByChild(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                         if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                             int userid_id = datas.child(userId).getValue(int.class);
                             tvEta.setText(Integer.toString(userid_id));
                         }
                     }
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                 }
             });
```

Is there any way to get the value directly from recyclerview without additional listener? or how can I retrieve this?

Comment: First step is to implement `onCancelled` as you may now be ignoring errors. At its minimum it should be: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Have you implemented onCancelled()? Is there something printed out in the console?

Comment: yes but nothing printed out